# Issue while reading the text from file using batch file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I'm trying to write one batch file which will read text from a text file and set to a variable.

This is the text file.

**out.txt**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows NT\text1.txt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows NT\text2.txt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows NT\text3.txt
   3 file(s) copied.
```

Here my doubt is I want to set **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows NT** to a variable. I tried with the following command which will hold the complete text file.

```
FOR /f "delims=/" %%a IN (out.txt) DO echo %%a
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I read a particular string from the text file.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to get the directory of every file specified in out.txt ? Maybe it would help if you show us the expected result

Comment: Here I want to store C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows NT\ in variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the full path of the files mentioned in `out.txt`, but without the filename. This can be done using [parameter extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html), like this:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (out.txt) DO ECHO %%~dpa
```

In your example, it will output

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows NT\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows NT\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows NT\
```

**Update:** To save *only the result of the first line*, use this:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (out.txt) DO (
    SET path_in_first_line=%%~dpa
    GOTO skip
)
:skip
ECHO %path_in_first_line%
```

Comment: In the above we got three lines of output. I want to hold the first line, C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows NT\ in a variable.How can I hold?

Comment: @Honey: In future postings you should include all important details in the original question and not complete it with comments in incoming answers (like "I want to hold the first line" point in this one); otherwise, each reply would answer a different question! If it would be necessary to add some information, you may _edit the question_ with a very clear **EDIT** mark before the changes and leave a comment in the answer that say: "See the edit in my question"

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, in future posting will remember all these.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the line using the backslash as a delimiter

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=\" %%a in (out.txt) do set "var=%%a\%%b\%%c"
echo %var%
```

Asking for the drive and path of the element in the line

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (out.txt) do set "var=%%~dpa"
echo %var%
```

Of course, as the `for` command iterates over all the lines in the file, the `var` variable will only hold the value retrieved from the last line in the file.